# Org calendar : change date language?

Tags: org-mode, calendar

I am able to set the date language with `(setq system-time-locale "LOCALE")` but it doesn't affect the calendar.

How can I change the language of calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Emacs Wiki node on calendar localization](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CalendarLocalization) explains how to do this.  For example, it shows that, for [Italian](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CalendarLocalization#toc11), you would want to do:

```
(setq calendar-week-start-day 1
          calendar-day-name-array ["Domenica" "Lunedì" "Martedì" "Mercoledì" 
                                   "Giovedì" "Venerdì" "Sabato"]
          calendar-month-name-array ["Gennaio" "Febbraio" "Marzo" "Aprile" "Maggio"
                                     "Giugno" "Luglio" "Agosto" "Settembre" 
                                     "Ottobre" "Novembre" "Dicembre"])
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly ! Is it possible also to change the title `Week-agenda (W02)` to another language ?

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto: I don't know, unfortunately.  You can try asking a separate question and see if anyone else knows.